# applying transaction with WCF data service

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm facing a situation with using WCF data service (ADO.NET data service) . In the client side if I make an operation lets say , adding new user , and the operation failed for some reason , then if I fix the problem and try to make the operation again , I get user already tracked by the context . Is there an automatic way to clean the context history about this operation objects and try again .

Thanks in advance ...